# Nextjs breaks layout during build mode using Tailwind

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, preact

I have this dashboard layout that works perfectly in dev mode.

[image]

But as soon as I build the nextjs project, it breaks the layout.

[image]

I am using Tailwind css and preact for production.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

The build was fixed by adding all the folders which contain tailwind css in taliwind.config.js in purge array like this...

[image]